# My sites not creating site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-farm

**Steps**
1) Created a web application `https://site`.

2) Configured user profile ,search and metadata.

3) Created a Team site collection at the root i.e.`https://site`

4) Create a Explicit path at 'my'

5) Created a wildcard path at my/personal'

6) Created mysite host site collection at `https://site/my/personal.`

7) Configured  Self Site Creation and set the path to https://sites/my/personal[%usersid%]

8) Under **Setup my sites** in User profile service application I have set the MySite Location to My/personal.

9) The user profile site collections are not created. I have enabled self site creation using the ui and powershell for the web application.

The my sites opens but the site collection for the user is not created. It points to `https://site/my/personal/person.aspx`

10) Set the thumbnailphoto property for the picture and ran a full synch

11) The import worked after 3 to 4 full synch

12) In **MIISCLIENT.EXE** when the sync runs it shows connections successful but o adds or deletes for the **export**.

Comment: do you have a top level site collection for the root '/'?

Comment: yes I have top level site collection at root'/'

Comment: Just a quick note: Make sure that your Content databases is not set to "offline" mode

Comment: And I assume the UPS service user should have at least write permissions (test it with db owner first) on the content DB. Check the ULS logs for potential errors when the my sites should have been created.

Comment: why you are using 2 managed paths? it should only use 1. i.e my or personal. Change it in my site host setup in UPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the Mysites using a [powershell](http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/script-creating-sharepoint-user-mysites.html) script

```
 $site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($MySiteRootURL);            
 try            
 {            
  $serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;            
  $upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);             
  if($upm.UserExists($Username) -eq $false)            
  {            
   Write-Host "User $Username was not found in the profile store." -f yellow;            
   return;            
  }            
  $userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile($Username);            
  if($userProfile.PersonalSite -eq $Null)            
  {            
   Write-Host "Creating MySite for user $Username" -f darkyellow;            
   $userProfile.CreatePersonalSite();                  
   Write-host "Successfully created MySite for user $Username" -f green;            
  }            
  else            
  {            
   Write-Host "User $Username already has a MySite." -f darkgreen;            
  }            
 }            
 catch            
 {            
  Write-Host "Encountered an error creating a MySite for user $Username. Error:"$_.Exception -f Red;            
 }            
 finally            
 {            
  $site.Dispose();            
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of steps required in order to configure the MySites.

- Make Sure UPS & MMS are up and running.
- Create  a Web application and create root site collection with MYSiteHost template
- in the Mysite Host location at UPA, give the root level site collection address
- then set the permissions.
- Enable Self-Service Creation

read more over here:
http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-my-site-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Ups and MMS is working .I have set the mys ites permission. I have aslo enabled self service creation.  I have set the mysite host location to personal.  I have a site at the root i.e. a team site and a myssiteat https://site/my/personal

Comment: Is the root level site collection is mysite host and same url in the UPA's mysite host location?

Comment: The root level site collection is https://site  which is a team site. The mysite is https://site/my/personal .UPA's mysite host location is personal.

Comment: I think MySite host site should be root level of your Web Application other wise it will not work...so create "/" site collection with mysite host template.

Comment: I can't remove the team site from the root site.It is one of requirements.Would it work if I add an explicit inclusion path say my and create the my sites under it. as suggested  by this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a wildcard managed path named "/my/personal". Having your Personal site host in /my/personal is not a functional design. It should be the root site collection of your web application.

Comment: The Root site is a team site.  I can't change the current design to the root site. The same setup worked when I installed it another environment .

Answer (score 0):

Certainly Technet seems to suggest that this is achievable though I haven't seen it. Have you got a test farm which you can try things out on?

Anyway I think the issue is that the user profile service app doesn't have the right location as to where to create my sites.

I would do the following:-

Test config out in test farm first

Remove existing my site host site collection

Create new explicit manaGed path /my so you have https://site/my

Create my site host site collection at https://site/my

Check user profile settings for where users my sites are created default to /personal or in your config https://site/personal

My site host is changed to https://site/my/

Check that users have permissions in user profile service app to create a my site (manage permissions link)